# Creating a trace plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I'm fairly new to using R so I'm sure I'm probably making a few rookie mistakes, but I can't seem to figure out how to create a trace plot for this homework question.

Here's the question:

On any given day, Gary is either cheerful (C), so-so (S), or glum (G). If he is cheerful today then he will be C, S, or G tomorrow with respective probabilities 0.5, 0.4, 0.1. If he is so-so today then he will be C, S, or G with probabilities 0.3, 0.4, 0.3. If he is glum today, he will be C, S, or G with probabilities 0.2, 0.3, 0.5. This can be used to make a 3-state Markov Chain with the following transition matrix:

```
[0.5 0.4 0.1    
 0.3 0.4 0.3 
 0.2 0.3 0.5]
```

Let the chain run for 50 times and create a trace plot for these 50 steps in R. You may write the code yourself or find an appropriate R package to simulate this.

I've made the matrix and *I think* I've run the chain 50 times, but can't get the traceplot() function to work.

```
library(coda)
library(markovchain)

p <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5)    
PP <- matrix(p, 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
mc1 <- new("markovchain", transitionMatrix = PP, states = c("C", "S", "G"), name = "Weather Forecast")
outs <- markovchainSequence(n = 50, markovchain = mc1, t0 = "C")
my_outs <- mcmc(outs)
traceplot(my_outs, smooth = FALSE, col = 1:6, type = "1", xlab = "Iterations", ylab = "oxygen", xlim = 50, ylim = 1)
```

This is the error I've been getting and I'm at a loss of what I need to do to get this to work or what other errors I've made before hand.

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value    
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Here's the example trace plot our professor gave us

[image: traceplot]

Comment: What packages are you using exactly? It doesn't look like `markovchainSequence` and `traceplot` come form the same package so they are likely incompatible.

Comment: I've been using Markov Chain, I tried to use mcmcplot and coda because someone on a different site suggested it, but now I think I've just confused myself with all the different packages I have.

Comment: Yeah, i think that's what's going on. Perhaps it would be better to describe what you want your final plot to look like. You may be able to extract the data you need easily from your markovchainSequence object.

Comment: I've added the picture of a traceplot our professor gave us as an example if that helps.

Comment: Your trace plot is just like a plot of the history of the sampling of the parameter of interest, right? like y (state value) ~ x (iteration). But in your case, you are like sampling a categorical one - why not try to make an ordinary plot, `plot(x =  1:length(outs), y = factor(outs), type = "n")`; then, `lines(x =  1:length(outs), y = factor(outs))` this should somehow tell you how the value change through iteration.